# Indentation in a custom TraceListener

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

How should I implement supporting indentation in a custom TraceListener?

```
Trace.Indent();
// or
Trace.Unindent();
```

Does not work even if there is an implementation for:

```
protected override void WriteIndent() { ... }
```

In that custom TraceListener.

Am I missing something?

Comment: So, was some of the suggestions useful?

Comment: Please see my replay (codes are messed up in comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out as those 2 static methods of Trace change IndentLevel. So I am doing this:

```
...
if (entry.IndentLevel > 0)
    writer.WriteLine(
        new string(' ', entry.IndentLevel * IndentSize) +
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `TextWriterTraceListener` class. It supports indentation.

Comment: Thank you. TextWriterTraceListener is not multi-threaded. BTW my trace listener is working fine now (yet! because it is a multi threaded application...you know ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to call [WriteIndent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.writeindent.aspx) explicitly yourself (if I interpret correctly the documentation). This code works as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program {

    class TestListener : TraceListener {

        protected override void WriteIndent() {
            if (NeedIndent) {
                string indent = new string(' ',IndentLevel * IndentSize);
                Console.Write(indent);
            }
        }

        public override void Write(string message) {
            WriteIndent();
            Console.Write(message);
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message) {
            WriteIndent();
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }


    public static void Main(params string[] args) {

        Trace.Listeners.Add(new TestListener());
        Trace.IndentSize = 2;
        Trace.WriteLine("test");
        Trace.IndentLevel = 4;
        Trace.WriteLine("indented");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done something similar. I noticed that Trace.Indent and Unindent changes IndentLevel. I am using that property to find out if it is necessary to insert indents.